# Removing a hash from an array of hashes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

```
h = {
    :vehicle => [
        [0] {
            :make => "Honda",
            :year => 2010
        },
        [1] {
            :make => "Kia",
            :year => 2014
        },
        [2] {
            :make => "Saturn",
            :year => 2005
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to remove `{:make=>"Kia", :year=>2014}` so that `h` is:

```
h = {
    :vehicle => [
        [0] {
            :make => "Honda",
            :year => 2010
        },
        [1] {
            :make => "Saturn",
            :year => 2005
        }
    ]
}
```

**I tried:**

```
h[:vehicle].delete_if{ |_,v| v == "Kia" } 
 #=> does nothing

h.delete_if{ |_,v| v == "Kia" } 
 #=> does nothing

h[:vehicle].tap { |_,v| v.delete("Kia") } 
 #=> does nothing

h.delete("Kia") 
 #=> nil

h[:vehicle].delete("Kia") 
 #=> nil
```

**Here's where I'm getting a headache:**

```
h[:vehicle].include?("Kia") 
 #=> false 

h[:vehicle][1] 
 #=> {:make=>"Kia", :year=>2014} 

h[:vehicle][1].include?("Kia") 
 #=> false
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
h[:vehicle].delete_if { |h| h[:make] == 'Kia' }
```

Will return a copy of `h` with Kia removed. Note that although its a somewhat strange way to do it, your first example does work for me. Remember that you have to look at the returned value to see the result - `delete_if` does not modify the original hash.

Comment: You're saying `h[:vehicle].delete_if{ |_,v| v == "Kia" }` this works?

Comment: Yes - here is what I get in irb: `h[:vehicle].delete_if{|_,v| v == "Kia" } #=> [{:make=>"Honda", :year=>2010}, {:make=>"Saturn", :year=>2005}]`

Comment: This is why my brain is hurting right now... Here's what I get in irb:  `2.1.0 :135 > h[:vehicle].delete_if{|_,v| v == "Kia" }
 #=> [{:make=>"Honda", :year=>2010}, {:make=>"Kia", :year=>2014}, {:make=>"Saturn", :year=>2005}]` What version are you running? I'm guessing not 2.1?